# Magento 2 Admin user role page show Blank

Tags: php, magento, admin, magento2

In `magento 2.2.0`, user role pages shows blank. What missed in this?
 - I cleared cache.
- Removed `var/cache` 
- Removed `var/page_cache`
- Removed `var/view_preprocessed`
- run **php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy**
Is any other issue in this version or anything have to do?.,

[image]

Comment: is it any js errors in console?

Comment: - no js errors in console.

Comment: Please try to upgrade & compile again....if there is any error in any file then you will get in compile command. Hope this will help

Comment: Have you removed "generated" folder code? in magento 2.2.* it was added at magento root folder

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that one of your modules doesn't have a title defined in the acl.xml file. The easiest way to fix this is to update in `src/vendor/magento/module-integration/Helper/Data.php` to have:

```
$item['data'] = isset($resource['title']) ? $resource['title'] : '';
```

This will enable the UI to load but for one or many of the modules will have a blank space next to the folder. You then need to let the module developer know to fix the issue, but as a short term fix just add a title attribute to the acl.xml for the module yourself. You can work out which module by inspecting the element.

Answer (score 0):

i had only to run and issue fixed!

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```